# combine multiple row in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I wonder if there is any easy way to combine multiple rows into one in Pyspark, I am new to Python and Spark and been using Spark.sql most of the time.

Here is a data example:

```
id      count1    count2   count3
 1       null       1       null
 1        3         null    null
 1        null      null      5
 2        null      1        null
 2        1         null     null
 2        null      null      2
```

the expected output is :

```
 id      count1    count2   count3
 1       3          1       5
 2       1         1        2
```

I been using spark SQL to join them multiple times, and wonder if there is any easier way to do that.

Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure if it was intended, but in your data, it looks like every id has only one non-null value for a column?

Comment: if every id has only one non-null value, you can do `groupBy` + [`first`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.first) with `ignorenulls =True`. Something like: `df.groupBy('id').agg(*[first(c, True).alias(c) for c in df.columns[1:]])`

Comment: Or `groupBy` with `max` : `f.groupBy("id").agg(*[max(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns[1:]]).show()`...

Comment: yes, only one null value. Thank you all, I will give it a try!

Answer (score 3):

Spark SQL will sum `null` as zero, so if you know there are no "overlapping" data elements, just group by the column you wish aggregate to and sum.

Assuming that you want to keep your original column names (and not sum the `id` column), you'll need to specify the columns that are summed and then rename them after the aggregation.

```
before.show()                                                                                                                                                                                      
+---+------+------+------+
| id|count1|count2|count3|
+---+------+------+------+
|  1|  null|     1|  null|
|  1|     3|  null|  null|
|  1|  null|  null|     5|
|  2|  null|     1|  null|
|  2|     1|  null|  null|
|  2|  null|  null|     2|
+---+------+------+------+

after = before
   .groupby('id').sum(*[c for c in before.columns if c != 'id'])
   .select([col(f"sum({c})").alias(c) for c in before.columns if c != 'id'])

after.show()                                                                                                                                                                                       
+------+------+------+
|count1|count2|count3|
+------+------+------+
|     3|     1|     5|
|     1|     1|     2|
+------+------+------+
```